# How to get .msg file out of signed mail?

Tags: c#, email, outlook, outlook-addin, signed

I am unable to save the .msg file out of a signed mail. I can save every other .msg file but am getting an exception when trying to save the .msg file from a signed mail. Below you can see the code I'm using. The exception is thrown at the `mailItem.SaveAs` line.

```
if (selObject is Outlook.MailItem)
{
    Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (selObject as Outlook.MailItem);
    mailItem.InternetCodepage = 65000;

    string sIsSigned = mailItem.MessageClass;

    sSubject = mailItem.Subject;

    if (sSubject != null)
    {
        if (iSubject < sSubject.Length)
        {
            sSubject = sSubject.Substring(0, iSubject);
            Logbuch.LogWriter("Subject: " + sSubject, sSavelog);
        }
    }

    string rename = sSubject.Replace("!", "").Replace(@"""", "").Replace(":", "").Replace(@"\", "").Replace("~", "").Replace("$", "").Replace("%", "").Replace("§", "").Replace(@"\", "").Replace("[", "").Replace("<", "").Replace("*", "").Replace(">", "").Replace(@"/", "").Replace("?", "");
    MsgFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Temp") + "\\", rename + "_" + thename + ".msg");
    sAdress = mailItem.SenderEmailAddress;
    if (sAdress != null)
    {
        if (iSender < sAdress.Length)
        {
            sAdress = sAdress.Substring(0, iSender);
            Logbuch.LogWriter("Absender: " + sAdress, sSavelog);
        }
    }
    sCC = mailItem.CC;
    if (sCC != null)
    {
        if (iCC < sCC.Length)
        {
            sCC = sCC.Substring(0, iCC);
        }
    }

    sBCC = mailItem.BCC;
    if (sBCC != null)
    {
        if (iBCC < sBCC.Length)
        {
            sBCC = sBCC.Substring(0, iBCC);
        }
    }
    DateTime Date = mailItem.ReceivedTime;
    FinalDate = Date.ToString().Substring(0, 10);

    mailItem.Permission = OlPermission.olUnrestricted;

    try
    {
        mailItem.SaveAs(MsgFile, Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Logbuch.LogWriter(ex.ToString(), sSavelog);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to provide the error you're receiving?

Comment: HRESULT 0x80004004 (E_ABORT) thats the error im receiving

Comment: Can the message be opened and saved from Outlook? Do not modify the message - that will break the signature.